# Google Drive API responds with 416 HTTP code

Tags: java, http, google-drive-api

For some reason the previously working code stopped working and server started to respond with 416.

Here are the logs of HTTP client during failing interaction:

```
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B02Nopv3SQOvOVNKaDIwTEZ3MHd?alt=media
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: &lt;Not Logged&gt;
Range: bytes=0-33554431
User-Agent: My app Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.22.0 (gzip)

-------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 416 Requested range not satisfiable
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
Server: UploadServer
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Range: bytes */0
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UqBx9B09Lnr8tG761gdoz3DkhHSNO_OzHh1LkU6B2908v17rnBGQZSNW4ZVTjbRdFtvPWWIqZGdtSrTo6ZWN7YW9nxf6d
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
Expires: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 15:23:20 GMT
Content-Length: 225
Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 15:23:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I was trying to download a file which is around 200000 bytes, so I thought meaning of "chuck size" changed somewhere, so it could not give 33554431 bytes of a 282177 byte file. Tried changing that to a smaller value, but no success.

```
Drive.Files.Get get = drive.files().get(file.getId())

MediaHttpDownloader downloader = get.getMediaHttpDownloader()

downloader.directDownloadEnabled = false

localFile.newOutputStream()
get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(stream)
```

Direct download does not work either, it just downloads "0" bytes.
Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a web interface when using Firefox. It uploaded "empty" files in certain cases.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/S03wEknc75g;context-place=forum/drive

Answer (score 0):

> [416 Range Not
>   Satisfiable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/416)
>   error means the server is not able to serve the requested ranges. The
>   most likely reason is that the document doesn't contain such ranges,
>   or that the Range header value, though syntactically correct, doesn't
>   make sense.

One of the resolutions that may provide from this [forum](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68298) is to:

> Add "Accept-Ranges: none" to our response headers.

Comment: I'll try that, but on MDN it is stated that Accept-Ranges is a response header, i.e. should be set on server side https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges